# How to rotate a view in 3d by 360 degree?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, rotation, catransformlayer

I am developing an app in which i am rotating a view by 360 degree but i am not able to rotate it 360 degree.
It is getting rotated by 180 degree and after getting rotated it is coming back to it's original position..

```
animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(3.14f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  
value = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform]; 
[animation setToValue:value];
[animation setAutoreverses:YES]; 
[animation setDuration:0.9];
[[rotatBall layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"180"];  //rotatBall is a view
```

In other words,it is making back and forth rotation.
How to rotate it continuously....
Kindly help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a little bit tricky but you can find it in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004511-CH1-SW5).
To rotate it continuously you first need to set the `toValue` then set the animation repeat count to `HUGH_VALF` (defined in math.h).

```
    CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.x"];

    transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  
    fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform];

    transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI*2, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  
    toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform];

    animation.fromValue = fromValue;
    animation.toValue = toValue;
    animation.duration = 0.9f; 
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;     // HUGE_VALF is defined in math.h so import it
    [rotatBall.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotation"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Your animation is reversing after it finishes because you set `autoreverses` to `YES`. That's what `autoreverses` does.

As for why you're rotating by 180 degrees instead of 360... how many radians is 360 degrees?

Comment: 2 radians but whenever i am writing 2 it does not even move

Comment: You might want to [check your math](http://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+radians+is+360+degrees). Also, you might find the constant `M_PI` helpful.

Comment: i meant 180*2 ...even i wrote 6.28 but no result..help please